# Replication Management Objects under SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, merge-replication, rmo

we are using SQL Server 2008 with merge replication. Our business application uses the rmo api, which we have installed with SQL Server Feature Pack 2008 SP3 and there the package sql_rmo.msi.

Now we want use SQL Server 2012 or 2014. In SQL Server 2012 Feature Pack I can not find such a package.

How can I install the rmo-lib's for SQL Server 2012 / 2014?

regards Jan

Comment: This might be a better fit for http://dba.stackexchange.com .

Comment: ok, here is the post:https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77522/merge-replication-api-with-sql-server-2012-2014